# Trouble with Carrierwave::MiniMagick and photo resizing

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to implement a resizer for images that are uploaded to my rails app but it's not resizing anything.

**uploader/picture_uploader.rb**

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

And here is the uploader:

**home.html.erb**

```
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
```

How can I make the images upload so they're all the same size?